# CSOM: Can access SharePoint ListItems of one list, but not the other

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, .net

I have two lists (Red and blue) on the same domain, but can only fetch list items from one of the lists. I can see item count, id etc. of both lists. My app has all rights to Sharepoint

This is my code

```
ClientContext clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientID, clientSecret);
        
        try
        {
            var oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(Guid.Parse("*ListGUID*"));
            clientContext.Load(oList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            
            ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
            clientContext.Load(collListItem);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log or output the exception details
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

[image: Blue count]

[image: Blue list]

[image: Red list]

[image: Red count]

[image: App rights]